# How to create this View(layout)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

Actually i am working on a layout in which i have to put **CardView** on a ImageView and it only covers the half portion of a ImageView and also add one TextView(Check Attach Image).

**Note:**

1. I tried using FrameLayout and also with Relative Layout...
   and i achieved it but i don't think its a correct way because i hardcoded mostly paramters.

[image]

**xml code :**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/picture">
</ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:text="TEXT VIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it?If yes then post the xml code

Comment: please check my code

Comment: hey bro you have given hard coded margins in your code

Comment: tell me in detail how do you want it to get implemented il send you the code accordingly. I had post that code before your edit

Comment: actually my code works perfectly but in my code i added `android:layout_marginTop="153dp"` in cardview...
so it create differnce margin when i check on different mobile...
so is there any way to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you don't want to hardcode parameters then refer this link to get device width height at runtime

[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

and then you can use LayoutParams to set margins dynamically.

Comment: actually i don't want to hardcode the parameters( android:layout_height="200dp")

Comment: oky so i have doubt,
is der any need to create multiple screen size xml?

Comment: @DhruvTyagi what you can do is you can use two views one of which will be match_parent in its width and android:layout_centerVertical="true" so this will divide your height in two parts then into upper half use the same method to further divide the upper half into two parts. Then you can make your imageview to alignParentTop and above your view so you want need to harcode values

Comment: @DhruvTyagi yes you have to create multiple xml files and if you want me to send you the xml with view then tell me i will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135759/discussion-between-kunal-parikh-and-dhruv-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this I have edited your code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/picture">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:text="TEXT VIEW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlueColor"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:arc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1s"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/done" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1s"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```